# MediaWiki API: size at which images where embedded/dropping unrelated icons

Tags: image, icons, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I use the MediaWiki API to find images of Wikipedia articles. However, I also get all the useless icons, like the broom for when a article needs to be cleaned up or the creative commons logo that marks something to be placed under a creative commons license.

Is there a way to detect which images are such icons so I can drop them? E.g. is there a way to query the size at which the image was embedded (rather then the size of the original image, which might be huge even for icons) so that I can drop all small ones. I'm not really interested in very small images anyway.

Comment: Nowadays class=metadata is used too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no.  That information is simply not stored in the database, and is therefore also not available via the API.

Some things you could perhaps do include:

- Load the HTML markup of the article (via the API [`action=parse`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse), or simply via index.php with [`action=render`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Action)) and extract the image sizes from it.
- Simply build a list of images that should be excluded.  You could do this programmatically (e.g. find all images used on all templates included in [Category:Wikipedia maintenance templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aWikipedia_maintenance_templates) and all its subcategories) or just add any unwanted images to the exclusion list as you come across them.